# Technique used in the news feed screen - custom view in the "new" Google Plus app - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android-scrollview

I would like to know some insights or ideas regarding the custom list like view in the new google plus updated android app. I'm specifically researching to know if this was a list view or a scroll view with inflated custom views in it.

P.S this also has a custom entry in animation when user scrolls which is giving me a doubt that this could also be a list view with custom adapter which has an animation when list items are recycled via getView.

Check the screenshot for some clear understanding.
[image]

Comment: For animation you can use this library https://github.com/cuub/sugared-list-animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have installed this app, but at least the way how it looks could be implemented with a `ListView`.
A custom adapter needs to be defined, and that custom adapter will inflate the layout for every entry, in the `getView()` method.

The layout of every entry, or with other words the layout of each row, could be represented by a `RelativeLayout` with all its components: The title, the +1 button, the photo, the date, etc.

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking too, but since it has like big images for every items to load, Is it a good approach to use lazy load technique or load 20 items and then scroll to the end and then load next 20?